# why does the FirebaseFirestore Transaction update not work?

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

Here is the code.The update not works and the count is still 0 after update.

```
FirebaseFirestore store = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;
CollectionReference globalRef = store.Collection("global");
DocumentReference doc = globalRef.Document("rank"+rankType);
store.RunTransactionAsync((transaction) =>
{
    return transaction.GetSnapshotAsync(doc).ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        if (task.Result.Exists)
        {
            int rank = 1;
            int count = 0;
            long t = 0;
            Dictionary<string, object> dic = task.Result.ToDictionary();
            rank = int.Parse(((Dictionary<string, object>)dic["data"])["rank"].ToString());
            count = int.Parse(((Dictionary<string, object>)dic["data"])["count"].ToString());
            t = long.Parse(((Dictionary<string, object>)dic["data"])["timestamp"].ToString());
            if (count >= 200 && timestamp > t)
            {
                transaction.Update(doc, "rank", rank + 1);
                transaction.Update(doc, "count", 0);
                transaction.Update(doc, "timestamp", timestamp + 3600);
            }
            else
            {
                transaction.Update(doc, "count", count + 1);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I want to increase the count and when the count reaches 200 the rank should be increased and reset the count to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the field count to `data.count`. It's not the problem of the transaction; the update works on the wrong field.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).